# Salesforce Order Activated

Tags: rest-api, rest

Is there a way to activate an order, using the REST API? I tried to send activated as the status when I create the order. Salesforce said it was an invalid status.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation for Order (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_order.htm) makes it sound like you need to set `StatusCode` and not `Status`. Does setting `StatusCode` to "Activated" work for you?